# Windows: How to initiate "modern" standby from session 0?

Tags: windows, winapi

Windows 8 introduced a new power saving mode called connected standby. In Windows 10, this was extended and re-named ["modern" standby](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/modern-standby). Some Microsoft documents refer to it as “S0 low-power idle mode” or "Always On / Always Connected". The new mode was initially used on the Microsoft Surface range and subsequently seems to be becoming more comment on other high-end laptop such as the Dell XPS.

Behind the scenes, the new power mode works differently to the normal S1-S4 power states.  Power saving starts when the display turns off and is transparent to applications. Microsoft claim that this will deliver faster suspend/resume and longer battery life. This has some interesting implications - desktop applications are not aware when this mode starts and must use the new [`RegisterSuspendResumeNotification()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registersuspendresumenotification) or [`PowerRegisterSuspendResumeNotification()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/powerbase/nf-powerbase-powerregistersuspendresumenotification) APIs to be notified. Systems supporting modern standby cannot also support S1-S3 but should support S4 (hibernate). This is used as a fall-back, when the battery gets low, to preserve data.

Traditionally, desktop apps could use the [`SetSuspendState()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/powrprof/nf-powrprof-setsuspendstate) to suspend (S1-S3) or hibernate (S4) the PC. However, this no longer works and attempting to suspend will fail with `ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED`. A workaround is to turn off the display directly. These seems to start the "modern" standby mode:

```
SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) 2);
```

This works fine, but can only be used from an application that has access to the display. It cannot be used in a service due to session 0 isolation.

Question: Is there a more generic API to initiate "modern" standby that can be used from a service running in session 0?

Comment: What about simply having the service spawn a child process in a user session and have that process issue the `SC_MONITORPOWER` message?

Comment: That would work if a user was logged on but would involve some undocumented tricks to get it to work (on the logon screen) when no user was logged on. I'm hoping there is a better way.

Comment: On further investigation, the Microsoft PwrTest tool achieves this by installing a virtual button driver and then pressing the virtual "power" button. It seems incredible that there isn't an easier way to put a modern system into the standby state.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in your boat with this one and I think the answers you got from Microsoft Q&A are correct, just incomplete.

In your service you need to do the following:

1. Get all the desktop sessions - [`WTSEnumerateSessions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsenumeratesessionsw) and select one or all the active ones (`WTSActive`).

   Maybe it's enough to just get the console session [`WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-wtsgetactiveconsolesessionid) and operate on that.
2. Once you have a relevant session, impersonate from your service the user in there, and launch a helper process as that user in that session.

   If you want to be cute, in your service's main you can differentiate between launch types:

   - "normal" launch - run as a service
   - "helper" launch (maybe based on command line parameters or the environment block) - run as a standard console subsystem application.

   i. To impersonate, you get the token from the target session:

   ```
   WTSQueryUserToken(session_id, &token);
   ```

   ii. Then build your own based on it:

   ```
   DuplicateTokenEx(token,
       TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT | TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID | TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_QUERY,
       nullptr, SecurityAnonymous, TokenPrimary, &token_new);
   ```

   iii. You edit your token, so that it's a token of *that* session and not of yours (ie not the useless service session 0):

   ```
   SetTokenInformation(token_new, TokenSessionId, &session_id, sizeof(session_id))
   ```

   iv. Might as well create a brand new environment variables block, for correctness:

   ```
   CreateEnvironmentBlock(&environment_block, token_new, FALSE)
   ```

   v. And finally launch the helper application:

   ```
   CreateProcessAsUser(token_new,
       nullptr, command_helper, nullptr, nullptr, FALSE,
       CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, environment_block,
       nullptr, &si, &pi);
   ```
3. The helper process should just do what Jeanine Zhang recommended - `SendMessage(handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 2);`. I'm not sure whether `handle` should be `HWND_BROADCAST` or `GetDesktopWindow()`, probably the desktop `HWND`.

Comment: Thank you. This is essentially the technique that I used. However, it was unsatisfactory few a few reasons. Firstly, the SendMessage() approach wasn't not 100% successful and occasionally the monitor would not standby. This contrasts with APIs like SetSystemPowerState() which are more consistent and provide useful error codes. Secondly, this technique would not work when no user was logged onto a session without further trickery to access the winlogon desktop. This seemed a potential security flaw and something I was reluctant to do (although it did work).

Comment: I'm still amazed that Microsoft didn't provide a consistent API to send a "Modern" PC to the standby state from a service. This seems like a big omission. They seem to tacitly acknowledge this in their own PwrTest tool which works around this by installing a virtual power button. That is a pretty extreme solution.