# SetThreadExecutionState with just ES_CONTINUOUS don't enable sleep on Windows 11

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-11, power-saving

I call `SetThreadExecutionState(ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | ES_CONTINUOUS)` and my PC doesn't sleep while a task is working. It's what I want.

When the task has finished, I call `SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS)`, and thought that the PC would be able to go to sleep, but it doesn't. It goes to sleep only if I send it to sleep manually.

How to return to the normal sleep timer?

PS: it's on Windows 11.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71664584/windows-how-to-initiate-modern-standby-from-session-0

Comment: Reproduced. It seems the sleep time adheres to the time of power plans and `SetThreadExecutionState` cannot interfere the internal timer. Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/999348/setthreadexecutionstate-without-es-continuous-does, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72436579/setthreadexecutionstatees-system-required-does-not-prevent-system-sleep-on-win

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found problem. I fired SetThreadExecutionState from different threads ;)